A finite sum involving alternate inverse binomial coefficients
$ \sum_{r=1}^{2023} (\frac{(-1)^{r-1}r)}{\mathrm{C}_{r}^{2024}}) $
My approach was to add up $1$st and $2023$rd term, $2nd$ and $2022$nd, $3$rd and $2021$st and so on
$T_r + T_{2024-r}=  \frac{(2024(-1)^{r-1})}{\mathrm{C}_{r}^{2024}} $
Cant think of anything beyond this

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Could you tell where this question is taken from?

Inspired from here,
$$S=\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}r}{\binom{2024}{r}}=2025\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}r}{2025\binom{2024}{r}}$$
$$=2025\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}r}{2025\binom{2024+r-r}{r}}$$
Note,
$$\frac{1}{2025\binom{2024+r-r}{r}}=\int_0^1 x^r (1-x)^{2024-r} \,dx$$
Or in general from here, beta functions for the win,
$$\boxed{\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^b=\frac{1}{\binom{a+b}{a}(1+a+b)}}$$
$$=2025\sum_{r=1}^{2023}{(-1)^{r-1}(r)} \int_0^1 x^r (1-x)^{2024-r} \,dx$$
$$=2025\int_0^1\sum_{r=1}^{2023}(-1)^{r-1}(r) x^r (1-x)^{2024-r} \,dx$$
Separating the $r$-dependent terms and taking a negative out,
$$=2025\int_0^1 (-1)(x-1)^{2024}\sum_{r=1}^{2023}(r)(x^r)(x-1)^{-r}\,dx$$
$$=2025\int_0^1 (x - 1) (x^{2024} (x - 2024) - x(x-1)^{2024}) \,dx$$
$$=2025\int_0^1 x(x - 1) (x^{2024} - (x-1)^{2024}) \,dx-(2024)(2025)\int_0^1 (x - 1) x^{2024}\,dx$$
Using this, we can eliminate the first integral,
$$=-(2024)(2025)\int_0^1 (x - 1) x^{2024}\,dx=(2024)(2025)\int_0^1 (1-x) x^{2024}\,dx$$
Referring above reference which is boxed, we get,
$$S=\frac{1012}{1013}$$
Found the generalized solution from my old notes,
$$\boxed{S=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{\binom{2n}{k}}=\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}\cdot r}{2024\choose r}&=\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}((r+1)-1)}{2024\choose r}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}(r+1)}{2024\choose r}-\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{2024\choose r}\\
&=2025\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{2025\choose r+1}-\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{2024\choose r}\\
&=2025\cdot\frac{1}{2025 \choose 2024}-\sum_{r=1}^{2023}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{2024\choose r}\tag{a}\\
&=2025\cdot\frac{1}{2025 \choose 2024}-\frac{1}{1013}\tag{b}\\
&=\frac{1012}{1013}
\end{align}$$
Explanations:
$\text{(a): Cancelling out equal terms in the first summation}$
$\text{(b): Using }$MSE 1402886$\text{ in the other summation}$
